# request.POST.get with django

Tags: python, django

Way one: not working

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        email    = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        print(username,email,password)
```

Way two: working

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data    = request.body
        convert = data.decode("utf-8")
        ds      = json.loads(convert)
        username = ds["username"]
        email    = ds["email"]
        password = ds["password"]
        print(username,email,password)
```

react function

```
  onSubmitSignUp = () => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/', {
      method:'post',
      headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body:JSON.stringify({
        username:this.state.username,
        email:this.state.email,
        password:this.state.password

      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(user => {
      if(user){
        console.log(user);
      }else{
          console.log("error");
      }
    })
  }
```

When I send data from frontend(react) via post method it is working in the second way.

I want the first one (django standard).

The first one is working in postman also but not in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you should send formdata to django server.
If you do want the first one,you should change the react code to this:

```
onSubmitSignUp = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', this.state.username);
    formData.append('email', this.state.email);
    formData.append('password', this.state.password);

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user);
            } else {
                console.log("error");
            }
        })
}
```